# Azure cloud based management system for virtual environments orchestration and life cycle management

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-devtest-labs

So basically I've been working with the [Neway Labs](https://labs-neway.com/) for a long time and I kept having issues with this software. For example you can't create an environment template and creating multiple environments for users can take up to 30-60 minutes of waiting.

I was wondering if there is another software like this one that works on Azure and basically does the same things only in which you have the ability to create an environment template and maybe a faster software?

Comment: pulumi, ansible, terraform? etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Azure DevTest Labs would be the service that you're looking for.

Azure DevTest Labs enables developers on teams to efficiently self-manage virtual machines (VMs) and PaaS resources without waiting for approvals. DevTest Labs creates labs consisting of pre-configured bases or Azure Resource Manager templates. These have all the necessary tools and software that you can use to create environments. You can create environments in a few minutes, as opposed to hours or days. Read more about its capabilities [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-overview).

For trying it out real quick, you may check the [Quickstart Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/tree/master/samples/DevTestLabs/QuickStartTemplates).

To know more about ARM support for this service, visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/allversions) link.

Hope this helps!